# Why $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ can be written of this way?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ a riemannian manifold. Let $r$ de radial distance i.e

$r(q) = |\exp_p^{-1}(q)|$

define

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \sum_i \frac{x_i}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$

in this [book](https://books.google.es/books?id=-SZ3QsgzQ6IC&pg=PA171&lpg=PA171&dq=is%20the%20velocity%20vector%20of%20the%20unit%20speed%20geodesic%20from%20p%20to%20q,%20and%20therefore%20has%20unit%20length%20with%20respect%20to%20g.&source=bl&ots=Q6waoQNG7D&sig=ACfU3U2zcc0CZGoRdZvU7M3xQ2paG5Es1w&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj10LL_9anhAhUlx4UKHccFACsQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=is%20the%20velocity%20vector%20of%20the%20unit%20speed%20geodesic%20from%20p%20to%20q%2C%20and%20therefore%20has%20unit%20length%20with%20respect%20to%20g.&f=false) said that

$\frac{\partial}{\partial r} = \frac{d}{dt}_{t = 0}\exp_p(t\frac{v}{|v|}+v)$

where $v \in T_pM$ with $\exp_p(v) = q$.

but why this is true??

Comment: We can't help you figure out why something is true unless we can figure out what you want to show is true. Most of these variables make sense, but what is $v$? Also a little more explanation would be helpful. Are you trying to define a radial tangent vector field around the point $p$ in some neighborhood?

Comment: Let $p \in M$ and $W$ a normal neighbourhood of $p$. We can choose $E_1,\dots,E_n$ orthonormal basis of $T_pM$ and define normal coordinates $X(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \exp_p(x_1 e_1 + \cdots + x_n e_n)$. As $\exp_p$ is a diff in $W$ we can choose $v$ with $\exp_p(v) = q$.

Comment: Isn't this question the same as your earlier  question?